# How can the card payment method be retrieved after card entry in Stripe IOS SDK

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe payment STPPaymentOptionsViewControlle which presents Apple Pay and Add New Card option. When the user pressed add new card it presents STPAddCardViewController. The UI flow works fine but I have been trying for days to get the paymentMethod when a card information is entered and still could not get it. Here is my code

```js
 


    struct PaymentOptionsView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate, STPPaymentContextDelegate {
         
        
        let paymentContext : STPPaymentContext

        // MyAPIClient implements STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider (see above)
        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeAPIKeyClient())
        
        var control: PaymentOptionsView

        init(_ control: PaymentOptionsView) {
            self.control = control
            self.paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)

        }
        
        func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
            
            print("[PAYMENTOPTIONSVIEW], @didFailToLoadWithError ")

             
        }
        
        func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
            print("[PAYMENTOPTIONSVIEW], @paymentContextDidChange ")

        }
        
        func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
            
            print("[PAYMENTOPTIONSVIEW], @didCreatePaymentResult ")

             
        }
        
        func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
            print("[PAYMENTOPTIONSVIEW], @didFinishWith ")
            
            switch status {
                case .success:
                    print("Payment done.")
                case .userCancellation:
                    print("User cancelled the trnsaction")
                case .error :
                    print("Error in payment.")
                default:
                    print("Unkown.")
            }

        }
        
        var currentPaymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod?
        //@objc private(set) weak var delegate: STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate?


     

        // Implement required delegate methods here:
        func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidCancel(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

        }

        func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {
            
            print("CARD DETAIL PROCESS HAS FINISHED \( paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption)")
            if paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption is STPApplePayPaymentOption {
            // Don't ask the user for their card number; they want to pay with apple pay.
            }
 
        }
        

        func paymentOptionsViewController(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

        }
        
        
        func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
              
           print("[ADDCARDVIEW], CARD TOKEN ", paymentMethod.stripeId)

            print(paymentMethod) 
        }
        func paymentOptionsViewController(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, didSelect paymentOption: STPPaymentOption) {
            print("CARD DETAIL PROCESS HAS FINISHED \( paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption)")
            if paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption is STPApplePayPaymentOption {
            // Don't ask the user for their card number; they want to pay with apple pay.
                
                print("APPLE PAY SELECTED \( paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption)")

            }
            
           

            if let currentPaymentMethod = paymentOption as? STPPaymentMethod {
                print(currentPaymentMethod)
                print("CARD DETAIL PROCESS as paymentMethod \(currentPaymentMethod.stripeId)")
            }else{
                print("NO PAYMENT METHOD")
            }
         }
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) -> STPPaymentOptionsViewController {
          let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
          config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full
          config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"
        return STPPaymentOptionsViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme(), apiAdapter: STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeAPIKeyClient()), delegate: context.coordinator)
      }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) { }
    
    
}
```

How can I get the entered payment method data after the entry of the card data?

Comment: is your didCreatePaymentResult() delegate method triggering?

Comment: @hmunoz No it's not. I'm not getting any print out

Comment: That means your delegate is not being set, I'm not sure how you do that in SwiftUI but you need to set up your STPPaymentOptionsViewController delegate.

Comment: @hmunoz do you have an idea on how to set the STPPaymentOptionsViewController delegate in the context of the code I posted